How do I apply functions to functions in Python?
Can someone explain the code below?
def mult_by_five(x):
    return 5 * x

def call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on arg"""
    return fn(arg)

def squared_call(fn, arg):
    """Call fn on the result of calling fn on arg"""
    return fn(fn(arg))

print(
    call(mult_by_five, 1),
    squared_call(mult_by_five, 1), 

How do I use the call function? What are fn and arg?

What happens when you tried it by running your program?

Justing noting this is common practice when you want to split logic of your app into easily testable methods...if you need more info than the provided answer this article does explain the process: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-call-function-from-another-function/

You are currently discarding the return value of call. If you didn't, you could see that call returns mult_by_five(1).

Functions in Python are objects, just like any other object. This means they can be passed around, and even after being passed around, they can still be called with the () operator.
The call function in this example takes two arguments- fn is a function and arg is the argument to pass to that function. So call(mult_by_five, 1) will result in mult_by_five(1) being called.
